# C# - Continuously listen to subscribed HTTP API

Tags: c#, http

I have a intercom which I can subscribe to certain events through the web API.

https://wiki.2n.cz/hip/hapi/latest/en/5-prehled-funkci-http-api/5-24-api-log-subscribe

I’ve tried different methods with a HttpListener but don’t get it to work, anyone have some ideas that might get this to work?

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;

namespace _2n_intercom
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var userName = "admin";
            var passwd = "admin123!";
            var url = "http://10.100.8.108/api/system/info";

            using var client = new HttpClient();

            var authToken = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{userName}:{passwd}");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                    Convert.ToBase64String(authToken));

            var result = await client.GetAsync(url);

            var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(content);

            string[] urlArray = new string[]{ url + "/" };

            SimpleListenerExample(urlArray);
        }

        public static void SimpleListenerExample(string[] prefixes)
        {
            if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Windows XP SP2 or Server 2003 is required to use the HttpListener class.");
                return;
            }
            if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

            HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();

            foreach (string s in prefixes)
            {
                listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
            }
            listener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Listening...");

            HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
            HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
            HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

            string responseString = "<HTML><BODY> Hello world!</BODY></HTML>";
            byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);

            response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
            System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
            output.Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);

            output.Close();
            listener.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you supply your code? It is very difficult to offer suggestions if we can't see what you have already tried.

Comment: Sorry, code added now :)

Comment: The linked page clearly states that `api/log/subscribe` will return a identifier to be used for pulling events. This means you need periodically make call to `/api/log/pull` to receive data. In HTTP protocol server will only send data if a client explicitly requested it. Your current code only calls server once at the start. I suggest you take a look at [Schedule a Task](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37252.c-timer-schedule-a-task.aspx) where the task will be called on certain intervals.